# Encoding user Input to get an encryption key

Tags: python, encryption, hash, cryptography, aes

I am taking in user input and need to turn it into an AES encryption key.
I have:

```
keyInput= input("Enter key:")
key = keyInput.encode()
print(key)
```

If I type in "computer" for the input. I get the result `b'computer'` for the output.

Shouldn't it look something more like this?

```
b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'
```

Comment: Hashing and encryption are different things. The former _should_ be used for password storage and verification (with more specific requirements); the latter _should **not**._

Comment: I have edited the post and would love some input. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to provide sufficient context. Ideally, you should give us a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, very new to stack.

Answer (score 2):

Long answer:  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53552/aes-with-small-and-large-string-keys

Short answer.  AES takes a 128-bit, 192-bit, or 256-bit key.  Some APIs let you use a **password** instead of a **key**.  How the password gets converted into the appropriate length key is not part of the AES standard.  There are a large number of "Password Based Key Derivation Functions" (PBKDF) that perform this function.

Answer (score 2):

`"computer"` cannot be an AES key because it only consists of ASCII characters. Keys for algorithms such as AES should consist of fully randomized bits and of course of a specific size (128, 192 or 256 bits).

What you are after is password based encryption. For this there are standards, such as [PKCS#5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8018), literally the "Password-Based Cryptography Specification" (Version 2.1). Basically it uses PBKDF2 to calculate a key from a relatively weak password using a salt and a work factor (or, in the case of PBKDF2, an iteration count).